# trying to save data that is in an array to a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, printing

This is my attempt at saving to a file. Once I enter the filename, it will save a file with that name, but it does not print anything to it and I dont get why.

```
if (menuoption == 6)
{
    printf("please enter a file name\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    filepointer = fopen(filename, "a");
    if (filepointer == NULL);
    {                           
        printf("unable to open file name: %s\n", filename);
        continue;
    }

    fprintf(filepointer, "decimal values:");

    for (int i = 0; i < doubcount; i++)
    {
        fprintf(filepointer, "%lf \n", doubles[i]);
    }

    fprintf(filepointer, "\n");

    fprintf(filepointer, "integer values: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < intcount; i++)
    {

        fprintf(filepointer, "%d\n", ints[i]);
    } 

    fprintf(filepointer, "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample I just wrote to show you how you should handle files in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(void){
            char* filename;
            FILE* fp;
            printf("Enter a file name:\n");
            scanf("%s", filename);
            fp = fopen(filename, "w");
            if(fp == NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open file name: %s\n", filename);
                    return -1;
            }
            fprintf(fp, "Testing\n");
            fclose(fp);
    }
```

First of all, you should use "w" instead of "a" in `fopen` function

```
fp = fopen(filename, "w");
```

You can read about the modes you can open a file here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

Then you should always close a file after reading or writing it, so add this line to your code

```
fclose(fp);
```

I hope this can work for your, unfortunately I couldn't run your code, because it lacks of variable declarations, includes and all other stuff